# Wordpress rewrite rules and custom optional arguments in url

Tags: php, regex, wordpress, url-rewriting

I am trying to build a filtering functionality for a Wordpress website using add_rewrite_rules. I have the following link example

```
 example.com/offers-type-all-inclusive-from-germany-transportation-airplane.html
```

Using the following rewrite rule:

```
add_rewrite_rule('^offers-type-?([a-z0-9-]+)?-from-?([a-z-]+)?-transportation-?([a-z0-9-]+)?.html','index.php?filters=offers&type=$matches[1]&location=$matches[2]&transportation=$matches[3]','top');
```

I managed to redirect the user to a custom page template with the arguments stored as an array

```
array(
    'type' => 'all-inclusive',
    'from' => 'germany',
    'transportation' => 'airplane'
     );
```

The problem is that some of the arguments could be optional so that links like

```
example.com/offers-type-all-inclusive-from-germany.html
example.com/offers-type-all-inclusive-transportation-airplane.html
```

also need to build the correct filtering array.

Is it even possible to achieve this?

Comment: Is it necessary to use "-" inside arguments when it is also used to divide them? why not example.com/offers-type/all-inclusive/from-germany/transportation-airplane ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What a tricky regex!

### Try this expression

```
offers-type-([a-z0-9-]*?)(?:-from-([a-z-]*?))?(?:-transportation-([a-z0-9-]*?))?\.html
```

### Here is an online demonstration

<kbd>http://regex101.com/r/fS4xB7</kbd>

Comment: It is working I have changed only into the following http://regex101.com/r/fS4xB7

But I also noticed that inverting the transportation part with the location it doesn't work anymore.